# Create a page loader timed to a single div (wrapper)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loader

I am looking for a solution for fast loading of the initial U/I of a page with large hidden modal content. My plan is to contain that visible U/I content in a wrapper and have a full-page overlay with a spinner dedicated to that wrapper that will clear once that wrapper content has loaded, even while the rest of the unseen modal content continues to load in the background. Can this be done?

```html
 <!-- Typical visible U/I beneath header after page load complete -->

    <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x">Modal Title</i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="###" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 
 <div id="bottomrule"><IMG SRC="###" WIDTH="1024" HEIGHT="25" BORDER=0><div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="navwrapper">
 <div id="bottomnav">Content</div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Typical Portfolio Modal -->
 
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="gallerytext">
             <img src="###" height="77" width="1024">
            </div>
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <img src="### width="800" alt="">
                        </div>
                        div class="modal-body">
                            <img src="### width="800" alt="">
                        </div>
                        div class="modal-body">
                            <img src="### width="800" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal footer">
             <img src="###" WIDTH="1024" HEIGHT="17" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="close-lowerlink" data-dismiss="modal">
                <IMG SRC="###" WIDTH="85" HEIGHT="32"></a>
             </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post some code! How is content being loaded into the modal?

Comment: Added some sample code (just the html). The thing I want to do is have the portfolio <section> wrapper be the element that times the loader. When all of the elements within the section wrapper are loaded, the loader (spinner) fades out and the page becomes accessible despite the hidden modal content continuing to load in the background. Is that possible?

Comment: *what* is loading the content though? Anything being loaded in via AJAX? Or does all this markup exist statically already? In which case do you mean wait until the images have loaded? More information on what your environment looks like, the better

Comment: Yes, it's all static content, so wait until the images have loaded within that wrapper but not until all of the hidden images outside that wrapper have loaded (as it is currently doing).

Comment: When I get a second I am going to experiment with using an array to preload all the visible images and a $.when or promise callback function to clear the loader when that array is loaded. I'm pretty new at scripting but perhaps this sparks some ideas...